# Android Random Background Image with background sound

Tags: android, audio, random, background, mp3

I have an Activity that if opened, it displays random background.

I was wondering if having a background with sound is possible in android.
Like if the background is Nature.jpg then the background audio is BirdsChirping.mp3. (So it matches the ambiance of the background.)

Like this:

```
> Nature.jpg = BirdsChirping.mp3 
> Ocean.jpg = Waves.mp3 
> Plane.jpg = JetEngineSound.mp3
```

Here is my current code:

```
//  RANDOM IMAGE
    int[] photos={R.drawable.nature, R.drawable.ocean};
    ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_bg);
    Random ran=new Random();
    int i=ran.nextInt(photos.length);
    image.setImageResource(photos[i]);
```

Comment: What's really our question here? you want us to help you with code for running a sound in Android?

Comment: Yes please. Running a specific sound depending what background will be displayed.

Comment: Please check my answer and try it then tell me if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put your mp3 files in a directory called `raw` then create an array named sounds with all your mp3 files IDs. This array's size should be the same size of the photos array and also be the same order so that the first file of photos array is correspondent with the first file of sounds array like the following code:

```
int[] photos={R.drawable.nature, R.drawable.ocean};
int[] sounds={R.raw.BirdsChirping, R.raw.Waves};
```

Then to play a sound you need to use `MediaPlayer`

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[i]);
```

This is how to initialize a MediaPlayer. The MediaPlayer follows the Static Factory Method Design Pattern. To get an instance, we call its create() method and pass it the context and the resource Id of the sound we want to play.

```
mp.start();
```

To play the sound, we call MediaPlayer's start() method. This method starts the playback of the sound.

```
    int[] photos={R.drawable.nature, R.drawable.ocean};
        int[] sounds={R.raw.BirdsChirping, R.raw.Waves};
        ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_bg);
        Random ran=new Random();
        int i=ran.nextInt(photos.length);
        image.setImageResource(photos[i]);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[i]);
        mp.start();
```

This is how your full code should be for playing a certain sound when a certain photo was set randomly in the background.

Comment: Wow! @EyadMhanna! Thank you! This is what I'm looking for! Your answer so far is the smoothest and most easy to understand that I have come across here in Stack. A detailed step by step tutorial with the complete answer at the bottom. I hope you can drop by again for my future questions. Kudos!

Comment: @GoodbyeWorld Thanks a lot for your kind words, I'm glad that my answer helped you. Your upvote and answer acceptance is very much appreciated. Happy Coding.